# C# integer masking into byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, byte, masking

I'm confused as to why this isn't working, can someone please provide some insight?

I have a function who is taking in an integer value, but would like to store the upper two bits of the hex value into a byte array element.

Let's say if Distance is (24,135)<sub>10</sub> or (5E47)<sub>16</sub>

```
public ConfigureReportOptionsMessageData(int Distance, int DistanceCheckTime)
    {
        ...
        this._data = new byte[9];
        this._data[0] = (byte)(Distance & 0x00FF); // shows 47
        this._data[1] = (byte)(Distance & 0xFF00); // shows 00
        this._data[2] = (byte)(DistanceCheckTime & 0xFF);
        ...
    }
```

Comment: You forgot the bitshifting...

Comment: BTW - what are you doing with the other 2 bytes in Distance?

Comment: @Reed Copsey: Nothing, there was a maximum set.  If it was meters, the limit was 30,000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this._data[1] = (byte)(Distance >> 8);
```

?

Comment: (byte)(Distance >> 8), not (byte)(Distance >> 16)

Answer (score 2):

This seems like you should be using [BitConverter.GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de8fssa4.aspx) - it will provide a much simpler option.

Comment: I think he heeds a 9 byte array. BitConverter.GetBytes would then need an Array.Copy or Buffer.Copy.

Comment: @codekaizen: Yeah, but I'd still say it's more maintainable, since it's obvious what's being done.

Comment: I somewhat disagree. After writing and maintaining a binary protocol handler, using BitConverter is less easy to maintain. Surprised me, too.

Comment: @codekaizen: Yeah - depends on how your data stream is coming into the routine.  In this case, converting from int to byte - I'd prefer to maintain somebody's code using BitConverter than bitshifting - especially given that it's going into a single large array.  Intent is easier to follow.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get `0` for `_data[1]` is that the upper 3 bytes are lost when you cast to `byte`.

Your intermediate result looks like this:

```
Distance && 0xff00 = 0x00005e00;
```

When this is converted to a byte, you only retain the low order byte:

```
(byte)0x00005e00 = 0x00;
```

You need to shift by 8 bits:

```
0x00005e00 >> 8 = 0x0000005e;
```

before you cast to `byte` and assign to `_data[1]`